# how to dynamically change the url option in dropezone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

i am working on dropzone.js for the first time to upload multiple files in a single go....But I am having some issues with it....
Basically what i am trying to achieve is upload multiple files against a meeting id i have a form in which there is an input field named as meeting_id and then i am programmatically creating dropezone.
below is my javascript code

```
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var arr=JSON.parse('<?echo $json_ext_arr?>').toString();
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myId", {
        url:'upload.php',
        autoProcessQueue:false,
        maxFiles:5,
        acceptedFiles: arr
       }); 

      });

          var meeting_id=$('#meeting_id).val()
```

now what i want is i want to change the url of the dropezone like

```
         url:'upload.php?meeting_id='+meeting_id+'';
```

where meeting_id is the value of the input_text name as meeting_id

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are after if I have understood your question correctly:

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var arr = JSON.parse('<?echo $json_ext_arr?>').toString();
                var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myId", {
                    url: 'upload.php?meeting_id=' + $("#meeting_id").val(),
                    autoProcessQueue: false,
                    maxFiles: 5,
                    acceptedFiles: arr
                });
```

Or you can do:

```
myDropzone.options.url = 'upload.php?meeting_id=' + $("#meeting_id").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue too while trying to update the url dynamically when a dropdown list option changes. But, it doesn't work when it is changed after the DOM is ready.

I could solve this issue by dynamically loading the Dropzone each time I change the option like below.

Step1: Define div container in the html like below

```
<div id="dzContainer">
<!--  Drag and Drop control is dynamically placed here to upload files to databse -->
</div>
```

Step2: Fill above div with Dropzone control

```
function ReloadDropZone(optionName) {

            //Create <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
            var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
            iDiv.id = 'dropzoneForm';
            iDiv.className = 'dropzone';
            document.getElementById('dzContainer').appendChild(iDiv);

            // Create <div id="innerDiv" class="fallback">
            var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
            innerDiv.id = 'innerDiv';
            innerDiv.className = 'fallback';
            document.getElementById('dropzoneForm').appendChild(innerDiv);

            /// Create <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
            var iInput = document.createElement('input');
            iInput.name = 'file';
            iInput.type = 'file';
            iInput.id = 'inputFile';
            document.getElementById('innerDiv').appendChild(iInput);
            document.getElementById('inputFile').setAttribute('multiple','multiple');

            ///<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            var iSubmit = document.createElement('input');
            iSubmit.value = 'Upload';
            iSubmit.type = 'submit';
            document.getElementById('innerDiv').appendChild(iSubmit);

            // Dropzone class:
            $("div#dropzoneForm").dropzone({
                url: 'apiurl' + optionName,
                dictDefaultMessage: "",
                autoDiscover: false,
                maxFiles: 2000,
                maxFilesize: 0.2,
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
                complete: function (file){},
                error: function (file, response) {},
                init: function () {}
            });
}
```